# Python code producing no output. Is the use of generator here correct?

Tags: python

So I recreated the sieve of eratosthenes but the result (prime numbers) is not output as i expected.

The first function is the sieve which returns a dictionary with all integers up to a given range as keys and True or False as their values (prime or not). The generator afterwards is supposed to get all the keys with a value of True (prime numbers). I think the problem is that I haven't used the generator correctly (I just learnt about generators), but I can't spot the mistake.

```
from math import sqrt

def sieve(x):
    values = {}
    for l in range(2, x + 1):
        values[l] = True
    for k in range(2, int(sqrt(x)) + 1):
        if values[k] == True:
            for j in range(k**2, x + 1, k):
                values[j] = False
    return values

def primes(dict1):
    for l in dict1:
        if l == True:
            yield list(dict1.keys())[l]

for k in primes(sieve(int(input()))):
    print(k, end = " ")
```

I expect all prime numbers (keys in the dictionary with a value of True) to be printed. But there is no output whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected version where you directly access the dictionary keys and values by iterating over them using `items()`. I have done some changes to the code:

- Store the user input in a variable called `number`
- Directly access the keys and the values by iterating over `dict1.items()`
- The point 2 simplifies the expression of `yield` in your original code.
- `if l == True:` can be simply replaced by `if value:`

---

```
from math import sqrt

def sieve(x):
    # function body here 

def primes(dict1):
    for key, value in dict1.items(): # <--- Directly access keys and values
        if value:
            yield key
number = int(input())

for k in primes(sieve(number)):
    print(k, end = " ")

# 15
# 2 3 5 7 11 13
```

Answer (score 0):

`for l in dict1` iterates over the **keys** of the dictionary, and the comparison `if l==True` expects a **value**. You can fix that, for example, by iterating over both keys and values using `items`:

```
for n, isprime in dict1.items():
    if isprime:
        yield n
```

A couple of unrelated notes:

- you probably want to use a list (or even an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)) of Booleans to store sieve data. Using a dict whose keys are consecutive numbers is wasteful.
- when testing a Boolean value, use `if x` rather than `if x == True`. The latter will give incorrect answer for truthy values other than `True`, such as 1 or a non-empty container. (To test whether `x` is false, use `if not x`.)

Comment: We think in a parallel universe in a synchronized fashion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a dictionary with `for l in dict1` yields the *keys*, not the *values*.

Therefore `if l == True` is never true.